# GRC QT GUI Range with slider presents error

Tags: python, qt, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

Using GNU Radio Companion 3.9.4.0.

My application has a "QT GUI Range" block.  When the Widget is set to "Counter + Slider" I get the error

```
TypeError: setRange(self, int, int): argument 2 has unexpected type 'float'
```

The Python code for this condition is,

```
self._rf_gain_win = RangeWidget(self._rf_gain_range, self.set_rf_gain, "RF Gain", "counter_slider", float, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
```

With the Widget set to "Counter" there is no error.  Now that same Python line is,

```
self._rf_gain_win = RangeWidget(self._rf_gain_range, self.set_rf_gain, "RF Gain", "counter", float, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
```

How can I use the desired slider?

= = =

The full error message is:

```
File "C:\Users\User1\Documents\Records\Software Defined Radio - SDR\GNU Radio\Flowgraphs\HackADay Tutorials\Video 02\Simple_AM_Rx_01_temp.py", line 100, in __init__
    self._rf_gain_win = RangeWidget(self._rf_gain_range, self.set_rf_gain, "RF Gain", "counter_slider", float, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
  File "C:\Users\User1\miniforge3\envs\gnuradio\lib\site-packages\gnuradio\qtgui\range.py", line 121, in __init__
    self.d_widget = self.CounterSlider(self, self.range, self.notifyChanged, rangeType, orientation)
  File "C:\Users\User1\miniforge3\envs\gnuradio\lib\site-packages\gnuradio\qtgui\range.py", line 262, in __init__
    self.slider = RangeWidget.Slider(parent, ranges, self.sliderChanged, rangeType, orientation)
  File "C:\Users\User1\miniforge3\envs\gnuradio\lib\site-packages\gnuradio\qtgui\range.py", line 161, in __init__
    self.setRange(0, ranges.nsteps - 1)
TypeError: setRange(self, int, int): argument 2 has unexpected type 'float'
```

Comment: The error message should tell you where the call to `setRange` is. What happens if you cast the offending argument to an `int`?

Comment: If I understand your question, the Python code is generated from the GRC block diagram.  The "QT GUI Range" block has entries for the desired range, and step.  Whether I enter an integer, 100, or a float, 100.0, the error recurs.  I am not sure what to cast and where to cast (in the GUI block?) to try your suggestion.

Comment: Please provide the full error message, which should be several lines.

Comment: I edited the original post above and added the full error message at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your traceback shows that the file `C:\Users\User1\miniforge3\envs\gnuradio\lib\site-packages\gnuradio\qtgui\range.py` has this line:

```
self.setRange(0, ranges.nsteps - 1)
```

but when I check the repository for this project [here](https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/blob/master/gr-qtgui/python/qtgui/range.py.cmakein) I see

```
self.setRange(0, int(ranges.nsteps - 1))
```

They corrected a bug. You are using an outdated version of the project.

Comment: I installed this from Conda only 2 days ago.  If I use the Conda update command will that bring in the bug fix?

Comment: I replaced the existing range.py with the file you identified in the repository which has the bug fix.  I had to replace line 12, viz., `@PY_QT_IMPORT@` with the line 12 from my original file, `from PyQt5 import Qt, QtCore, QtWidgets`.  Now the application and slider works.

Comment: @marcus-müller, As I noted above, this problem came with my Conda installation of Saturday, November 20 after our exchange.  The Conda instructions you identified for me strongly suggest identifying errors.  I would like to do that but am not sure how the file identified by @Passerby meshes with the Conda installation or if the bug has already been connected in Conda.  Second, is there a way to update my Conda installation which will have this bug fix?  The Conda instructions indicate that the command `conda upgrade --all` will only update non-Python packages.